# Java/Maven: different slf4j versions in different projects causing build errors on integration

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I have a `project A` whose `pom.xml` has the following dependency on `slf4j`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I have different `project B` whose `pom.xml` has following dependency on `slf4j`

```
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I need to **integrate** two projects but they don't play well together when they have different versions. So this is what I tried
**Approach 1 - Upgrading slf4j in `project A`**
After changing the `pom.xml` to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I started to see build errors saying

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.10 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

and tests seem to fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
```

**Approach 2 - Downgrading slf4j in `project B`**

After changing `pom.xml` like following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I see errors in tests as

```
testPutDocument(com.org.sparrow.business.persist.MongoServiceTest): org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
  testPutDocuments(com.org.sparrow.business.persist.MongoServiceTest): org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
  testGetDocument(com.org.sparrow.business.persist.MongoServiceTest): org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

**UPDATE**
dependency tree is here

```
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- spy:spymemcached:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode:hibernate-memcached:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- spy:memcached:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- j2ssh:core:jar:0.2.9-SR:compile
[INFO] +- emma:maven-emma-plugin:jar:0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  \- emma:emma_ant:jar:2.0.5312:test
[INFO] +- emma:emma:jar:2.0.4217:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-jelly:commons-jelly-tags-regexp:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- regexp:regexp:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-email:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:test
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-agent:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas-client:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jasig.cas:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:3.2.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |     +- freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- eu.medsea:utils:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- velocity-tools:velocity-tools-view:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jmock:jmock-junit4:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jmock:jmock:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- mapquest:mapquest:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.fraid.fraid:fraid:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:0.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- cdyne:cdyne:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- json:json:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] \- javatar:javatar:jar:2.5:compile
```

Comment: Approach 1 sounds like your best bet. Can you post the dependency:tree? It sounds like multiple slf4j bindings are getting pulled in, and one of them wasn't getting upgraded when you changed the version.

Comment: At that resolution, it is impossible to read. Perhaps just paste the results of mvn dependency:tree?

Comment: This appears to be pre-upgrade of SLF4j in project A. I don't see any odd dependencies here that should obviously prevent it from working after the upgrade. The warning that you received is the type of warning that you would received if you upgraded the API without upgrading the log4j binding, but your example doesn't seem to show that being the case. Does the Spring exception show any other details on what caused the bean to fail to start? I'm sorry, but I don't have a lot more ideas on this one...

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you did to **"integrate two projects"**? What are project A and B's packaging type?

Comment: I think we are missing something

> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 

... name ? It would give the exact config throwing the error, unless the bean name is null.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you mention that you upgraded slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 to version **1.6.4** in project **A**'s pom.xml but the dependency tree you posted mentions slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 version **1.5.0**. As long as you settle on a version so that slf4j-api and the version of its binding match, you will be fine.

It does not matter what SLF4J version your other dependencies declare for SLF4J. From the client's perspective [all versions of slf4j are binary compatible](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Jar projects for inclusion as libraries in other projects should not include anything in the POM other than slf4j-api. It's up to the final project (i.e. project A in your example) to decide on the implementation. For testing project B, it's acceptable to include an implementation such as slf4j-log4j12 and log4j itself, but these should be scoped `test` in Maven.